# PEX repipe and hot water issues

Tags: pex

We just repiped out 45 yrs old house with PEX and the whole process was very smooth and I’m glad we did this. I knew the water pressure would change going from 90 psi water pressure to I don’t know what but I feel like I’m taking a shower in slow motion now, but what I can’t figure out is why it takes what seems to be five minutes to get anywhere close to hot water. I turned the water heater up a little. I know it takes a long time to fill a pitcher of water so I figure that is the same with the water heater tank. Also, there’s about two feet of space between the walls bathroom opposite of kitchen and the kitchen faucet will sometimes have hot water seriously hot water coming out of the cold water setting.??? Any idea of what might be happening with this? Appreciate any suggestions for what it if anything I need to do here.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; hope the answer helps. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

Check all the aerators for clogs. When you repipe you can dislodge a lot of rust and gunk from the old pipes and it can clog the filters. Also check the shower heads for the same thing. If the problem is with a specific faucet you might want to remove and check out the cartridge.

Comment: Thanks I will do that. It never occurred to me that could happen and it totally makes since why now. I’ll let you know how if I find anything or not thank you Tracy